# Changing metadata using ArcPy of ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, metadata

Is there any ArcPy function or classes which allow us to change map and layout metadata within ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the [ArcGIS Pro Roadmap - February 2019](https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-13013-arcgis-pro-roadmap-february-2019#comment-70448) was released, I asked:

> Is the equivalent of ArcMap's Metadata Toolset expected to appear in ArcGIS Pro 2.4?

The response from KKramer-esristaff was:

> unfortunately the scripting capabilities will not be in 2.4, due to
>   the previously stated priority of supporting the new version of ISO
>   metadata standards.  Scripting is still in the plan, but not for 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS Pro now has a metadata object:
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/metadata/metadata-class.htm